# Create an input field using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

Im trying to create such element only with JS:

```
<input type="text" value="default">
```

To do so, I tried this code:

```
var mi = document.createElement("input");
mi.type= "text"
mi.value = "default"
```

But when I run it in Chrome Dev Tools, it only creates this element:

```
<input type="text">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you put in the code you're using to insert the element into the DOM as well?

Comment: What's wrong, doesn't the value show up in the page or on submitting?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Setting a *property* of a [*HTMLElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) isn't exactly the same as setting it's *attribute* to the same thing.

You most likely wanted to use [`element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute)

```
var mi = document.createElement("input");
mi.setAttribute('type', 'text');
mi.setAttribute('value', 'default');
```

Now you can see

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(mi);
// "<input type="text" value="default">"
```

In your example, the *value* displayed by the `<input>` will still be `default`, it just isn't set as the *attribute*.

Further note that if the user changes the *value* of `<input>`, e.g. types into it, setting the *attribute* will not change the *value* any longer, but setting the *value* property will still change it. Again, this is because an *attribute* is different to a *property*.

Comment: Note: To set or modify the current values, you should use the properties when possible. For example, use `elt.value = val` instead of `elt.setAttribute('value', val)`, due to inconsistencies across browsers and environments, most notably XUL and IE (IE with the use of `class` instead of `className`). Do a little search if you wish to know/understand more. +1. The OPs code should work fine though: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/cD8zZ/)

Answer (score 5):

```
var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
i.setAttribute('type',"text");
i.setAttribute('name',"username");
i.setAttribute('value',"default");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the ; after "text".

Comment: semicolons are not required... but preffered